# How to add class to a div that has adjacent sibling using javascript or react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i want to add a class to a div that has adjacent sibling selector.

Below is the html code,

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="prev_div">previous</div>
    <div class="next_div">next</div>
</div>
```

I want to add margin property to the div with class "prev_div". I tried doing that with css as below,

```
.wrapper div.prev_div + div.next_div {
    margin: 10px;
 }
```

But the above adds the margin to the div with class next_div instead i wanted the margin style for the prev_div.

So i tried doing the same using the javascript by finding the element with prev_div and next_div. if next_div present adding a class "additional" to the prev_div. once class additional added and if the next_div not present remove the additional class for prev_div. but this doesnt work...there is a delay in removing the class added when next_div not present.

```
render = () => {
    const prev_div = document.querySelector('wrapper div.prev_div');
    const next_div = document.querySelector('wrapper div.prev_div + div.next_div');
    if (next_div) {
        prev_div.classList.add('additional');
    } else {
        if (prev_div && prev_div.classList.contains('additional')) {
            prev_div.classList.remove('additional');
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help me fix this or provide a better solution to do this. thanks.

Comment: Your JS code works fine for me, except the fact that you miss the dot `.` in front of `wrapper`. If you add the dot in both places where you use that class selector in JS, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your js code is working, just missed dot . before wrapper

```js
 const prev_div = document.querySelector(".wrapper div.prev_div");
      const next_div = document.querySelector(
        ".wrapper div.prev_div + div.next_div"
      );
      console.log("prev_div", prev_div);
      console.log("next_div", next_div);
      if (next_div) {
        prev_div.classList.add("additional");
      } else {
        if (prev_div && prev_div.classList.contains("additional")) {
          prev_div.classList.remove("additional");
        }
      }
```

```css
.additional {
        margin: 10px;
      }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="prev_div">previous</div>
      <div class="next_div">next</div>
 </div>
```

Also there is more beautiful solution to add a class to element that has next sibling

```
const elem = document.querySelector(".prev_div");
      const isNexSibling = elem => {
        const nextSibling = elem.nextElementSibling;
        if (nextSibling) {
          elem.classList.add("additional");
        }
      };
      isNexSibling(elem);
```